# What does Ansible push to the remote host?

Tags: ansible

Wondering how Ansible works at a brick level. Most sites say a module is pushed and Ansible does not need an agent on the remote host - just SSH and Python.

It seems like Ansible would need to create a python script locally and copy it to the remote host. What is sent? Is it literally a `.py` file or a `.pyc` file - or other?

How is it possible the remote host will not need any additional Python packages?

Answer (score 9):

> Most sites say a module is pushed and Ansible does not need an agent on the remote host - just SSH and Python.

That's correct.

`scp` or WinRM might also be used, as well a handful of other [connection types](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/plugins/connection.html#plugin-list).

---

> It seems like Ansible would need to create a python script locally and copy it to the remote host. What is sent? Is it literally a .py file or a .pyc file - or other?

It does create a script locally and copy it to the remote host. `.py` or a packed set of those.

You can see for yourself -- execute Ansible with `ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES` set to `1`:

```
ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1 ansible-playbook playbook.yml
```

and check the temporary directory on the target machine (by default under the `$HOME/.ansible/tmp/` for the connecting user).

If the files were packed, there are instructions in the comments inside the file on how to expand the set.

---

> How is it possible the remote host will not need any additional Python packages?

This claim is incorrect.

There are many modules requiring additional Python packages, for example [`expect` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/expect_module.html):

> The below requirements are needed on the host that executes this module.
>
> - python >= 2.6
> - pexpect >= 3.3

or even executables, for example [`unarchive` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/unarchive_module.html):

> Requires `gtar`/`unzip` command on target host.

Comment: One note to further this: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/dev_guide/developing_modules_best_practices.html. You can use the explode command to 'turn the string into some python files that you can work with': ~/.ansible/tmp$ ansible-tmp-1536719125.6725047-209276989541110/setup.py explode

Comment: Isn't this what I wrote above? "*If the files were packed, there are instructions in comments how to expand the set.*"

Comment: Ansible needs python 2.6 on the remote end unless you use raw mode AFAIR